# Match values between two matrices based on max number of matches needed

Tags: r

I want to get only the rows from matrix A that have only any 5 or any 4 numbers  existing in matrix B. Is there an R function I can use to solve it?

Μatrix A

```
 1   2   3   4  5
 2   3   5   6  7
 3   5   7   8  1
 2   7   5   4  3
```

matrix B:

```
 1   2   4   5   6
 2   4   1   3   7
 3   5   7   9   8
 5   8   9   2   6
```

if I ask for 5 numbers from B to match rows in A I will get no matching row.

if I ask for 4 numbers from B to match rows in A I will get :

```
 B1 - A1
 B2 - A1, A4
 B3 - A3
```

Comment: How does B3 match with A1, A2 and B4 with A2?

Comment: you are right, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything built into R that will work, but this custom function may help you get what you're after.

```
find.matches <- function(A, B, num.matches){
  # Set rownames for the matrix
  rownames(A) = paste0(deparse(substitute(A)), 1:nrow(A))
  rownames(B) = paste0(deparse(substitute(B)), 1:nrow(B))

  # Create matrix indicating matching items
  out <- t(apply(cbind(seq_len(nrow(B)),B), 1, 
                   function(y) {
                     cur.b = y[-1]
                     res <- apply(cbind(seq_len(nrow(A)),A), 1, 
                           function(z) {
                             cur.a = z[-1]
                             ifelse(sum(table(cur.a[cur.a %in% cur.b])) == num.matches, rownames(A)[z[1]], NA)})}))

  # Create list of matching items
  out <- apply(out, 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)]))

  # Remove non matches from list
  out <- out[lapply(out,length) > 0]

  if(length(out) > 0){
    # Convert list to a vector
    out <- paste0(names(out), " - ", lapply(c(out), paste, collapse = ", "))

    # Print the vector
    cat(out, sep = "\n")
  } else{
    print("No Matches Found")
  }

}

# Create matrices to compare
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2,2,3,5,7,3,5,7,5,4,6,8,4,5,7,1,3), nrow = 4)
B <- matrix(c(1,2,3,5,2,4,5,8,4,1,7,9,5,3,9,2,6,7,8,6), nrow = 4)

# Compare matrices
find.matches(A, B, 4)
```